# Unable to send transactions with quorum nodes using tessera

Tags: blockchain, http-status-code-500, raft, quorum

I am unable send transactions between 2 quorum nodes on different machines using tessera privacy manager and raft consensus.(private-contract.js)
I am getting the following error

err creating contract

```
Error: Non-200 status code: &{Status:500 Internal Server Error StatusCode:500 Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:
```

Any solutions avaialble?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the quorum logs. There should be a message detailing why the contract creation failed. You may also need to check the tessera logs if quorum reported an issue when sending the transaction to tessera.